# How to convert QIcon to QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt3

I have following code and I have to change it with Qt4 code.

```
QIcon icon;
QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap();    // Qt3 code
```

for replacing Qt3 code with Qt4, I have to replace `pixmap()` with one of following methods provided by the Qt4.

```
QPixmap QIcon::pixmap ( const QSize & size, Mode mode = Normal, State state = Off ) const  
QPixmap QIcon::pixmap ( int w, int h, Mode mode = Normal, State state = Off ) const
QPixmap QIcon::pixmap ( int extent, Mode mode = Normal, State state = Off ) const
```

Since I don't know what size or dimension it is using in this call of `pixmap(void)`. So I need to find out alternative which can eliminate this code without asking explicitly size.

What I understand from this code segment. It is taking size of icon. So I try to find out size of icon. But again I do not find any method to get size of icon.

Comment: There are static methods `QIcon::pixmap()` for this (from [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qicon.html))

Comment: Did you see the QIcon documentation? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qicon.html

Comment: please refer to question again. I have updated it for more description.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`QIcon` may contain multiple images with different sizes, a *generic* `icon.pixmap()` is too much arbitrary (which size will be used to build `QPixmap`?). [`pixmap()` method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qicon.html) is still available but you have to specify which size you want.

If you know size then you can simply use:

```
QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(requiredImageSize);
```

If you don't (as in your case) then you have some alternatives. First you may ask for an image with a specified size (or less) using [`QIcon::actualSize()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qicon.html#actualSize) method.

```
QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.actualSize(QSize(32, 32)));
```

Suppsing `icon` contains 16x16, 24x24 and 64x64 then it'll return 24x24 (biggest image smaller than what you specified).

Second alternative is to pick biggest available image (assuming width and height are always equal) querying sizes using [`QIcon::availableSizes()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qicon.html#availableSizes):

```
QList<QSize> sizes = icon.availableSizes();
int maximum = sizes[0].width();
for (int i=1; i < sizes.size(); ++i)
    maximum = qMax(maximum, sizes[i].width());

QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(QSize(maximum, maximum));
```

Note that if you use first method and you specify a value big enough then you'll have same result:

```
QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.actualSize(QSize(1024, 1024)));
```

Of course you may also simply pick first/last available size:

```
QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.availableSizes().first());
QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.availableSizes().last());
```

Comment: For the second method this may or may not be slightly better: `QSize max(0, 0); for(QList<QSize> sizes =  icon.availableSizes(); !sizes.isEmpty(); sizes.removeFirst()) if(sizes.first().width() > max.width()) max = sizes.first(); QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(max);`